# volttron can not access to gui (error "Not Found")

Tags: volttron

I have a question about volttron.

I have installed volttron version 5.0beta, and access localhost:8080 (gui)

but, I can't access localhost:8080/index.html

they show a below picture.

How can you solve the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of vc has changed to allow other agents better usage of the web server. 
Please use http://localhost:8080/vc/index.html.